# Using PayPal Checkout API, the payee is ignored

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been trying to use the Checkout SDK to set up a payment to a 3rd party email address in the sandbox.  Everything works, but the payee email I specify in the request according to the docs is ignored and replaced by my other default sandbox account no matter what I set it to.  Could anybody advise on what I'm doing wrong?

This is the structure I'm using:

```
$request->body = [
    'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
    'purchase_units' => [
        [
            'amount' => [
                'value' => $amount,
                'currency_code' => $currency
            ],
            'payee' => [
                'email' => $payee->paypal_email
            ],
            'description' => 'One-time donation to ' . $payee->name
        ],
    ],
    'application_context' => [
        'cancel_url' => url('donation_error?' . $this->callbackQuery),
        'return_url' => url('donation_success?' . $this->callbackQuery)
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'email' => ...
```

This structure isn't right. According to the documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/) and [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-payee), the correct key name is `email_address`

Unknown keys like 'email' will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just code blind after all that